# Redux Pattern for Comparing a Cached State?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

Consider the following Redux code,

```
let cacheState = {};
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    const zug = cacheState.bar === state.bar ? "qux" : "doo";

    return {
        foo: state.bar,
        zug
    };

    cacheState = state;
};
```

This code example spurs the following observations:

1) This seems to be the only way to cache state in a Redux component

2) This will break if multiple Redux components are created from this template

3) This is an anti pattern

What is the correct way for a component to be aware of previous states?

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use middleware to accomplish this. When your store is created, you'd do the first comparison (say if you were using `localStorage`) and store the cached state. You would then assume both your store and cache are synced. Every action that follows would go through the middleware and sync the state back with the cache.

You're right that what you're doing here is an anti-pattern which is why the middleware approach is useful in avoiding it. Dan Abramov's second set of Redux videos goes over this exact pattern if you'd like to check em out by searching the *Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux* in Egghead, or [here](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux).